# How do I set a static address in a Pi, to an IP provided by my ISP?

Tags: static-ip

I have two static IPs from my ISP. I want to hang a Pi4 on one of them, and connect it through a switch to one of the IPs provided.
To be clear, suppose one of my IPs is 123.45.67.89
I want to plug my Pi into an unmanaged switch, and set it up to directly use that IP. The gateway would be 123.45.67.254

I previously had a Pi doing exactly that, but can't remember how I did it.

Comment: No more relevant to the Pi than any other Linux computer. Have you considered set up port forwarding on your router instead? Using a public IP address on your LAN doesn't look good to me.

Comment: Well, it won't exactly be on a LAN, unless you call a single Pi on a switch, a LAN.

Answer (score 2):

There is an official side where you can find how to setup a static ip address on a Raspberry Pi:
[TCP/IP networking](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/tcpip/).

Comment: Thanks Max, but that shows how to set a static address on a LAN. Could I just use:

static routers=123.45.67.254

which is the gateway?

Comment: Got it. Just set routers =123.45.67.254 and it works like a champ.

Comment: @lar3ry Please create an answer with the solution and mark it as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side after two days. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community all the time and saves them/us a lot of work.

Comment: Isn't that odd - that they would publish advice that's contrary to the published documentation? I suppose the Raspberry Pi Foundation employees don't read the fine manuals either!

Answer (score 1):

@MaxDZ8 pointed me to a site that told me to add the following entry to /etc/dhcpcd.conf:

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.4/24
static routers=192.168.0.254
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.254 8.8.8.8

This did not look like the solution I wanted, as my Pi is not connected to a router; only to an unmanaged switch. As it turned out, I added the following to /etc/dhcpcd.conf using my actual static IP and the gateway IP provided by my ISP.

interface eth0
static ip_address=123.45.67.89
static routers=123.45.67.254
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8